# Signtool error: An unexpected internal error occurred during Excel macros signing "Error: SignerSign() failed." (-2147220493/0x800403f3)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office, code-signing, signtool

I am encountering an error while attempting to sign Excel macros using SignTool. The error message I receive is as follows:

> "SignTool Error: An unexpected internal error has occurred. Error
> information: "Error: SignerSign() failed." (-2147220493/0x800403f3)"

To troubleshoot the issue, I have already taken the following steps:

Installed the Visual C++ 2010 redistributable.
Updated SignTool to the latest version.
Registered "msosip" and "msosipx".
Despite these measures, the error persists. I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and successfully sign Excel macros using SignTool.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: What is the exact path for the signtool.exe utility used? What is the exact command line used for signing the code?